# Matrix of Linear transformation of Polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, transformation

I'm having problems finding the Matrix T of the following linear transformation

$T\::\:R2\left(x\right)\:->R2\left(x\right)\:defined\:by\:T\left(ax^2+bx+c\right)=2ax+b$

so I know that a base of T is $(x^2,x,1)$, but im not able to get the im(T) to make the matrix any help?

Comment: Since you know the standard basis, why don't you apply the transformation $T$ to the three basis vectors?

Comment: Write each of the vectors $T(x^2),T(x),T(1)$ as a linear combination of the vectors $x^2,x,1$. Then, put the coefficients that you obtained in order to obtain the columns of your matrix. Do it everything in order!

Comment: like this   $T(x^2)=x^2(0,0,0)$ because there is no $x^2$ on $2ax+b$ ,T(x)=x(0,2,0) becaue we have 2 on x and T(1)=(0,0,0)??

Comment: Something like that, but just substitute $x^2 =1x^2 +0x+0$ in the defining formula to get $T(x^2) =2x$, its coordinates are $(0,2,0)$.

Comment: I'm not following

Comment: If we substitute $a=1,\ b=0,\ c=0$ in the definition of $T$, then we get $T(x^2) =2x$. Is that part clear?

Comment: got it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Polynomials are functions that are defined by the numbers that multiply $1, x, x ^ 2, x ^ 3, ....$ in the plots of the polynomial. That is, a polynomial of degree 2 or less, $ax ^ 2 + bx + c$, is defined by the numbers (or "coefficients") $(a, b, c)$.

If the base of ${R} _2 [x]$ (vector space of polynomials of degree not greater than 2) is $(x ^ 2, x, 1)$, the matrix of the linear application will have in the first, second and third columns, respectively, the coefficients of $T (x ^ 2)$, $T (x)$ and $T (1)$, that is, the coefficients of

$2x = 0  * x ^ 2 + 2  * x + 0  * 1$ (first column is $[0 \ 2 \ 0] ^ T$,

$1 = 0 * x ^ 2 + 0 * x + 1 * 1$ (second column is $[0 \ 0 \ 1] ^ T$ and

$0 = 0 * x ^ 2 + 0 * x + 0 * 1$ (third column is $[0 \ 0 \ 0] ^ T$.

as auxiliary calculus we have,

canonical basis $(x ^ 2, x, 1)$

$T (x ^ 2) = T (1x ^ 2 + 0x + 0) = 2 * 1 * x + 0 = 2x$

$T (x) = T (0x ^ 2 + x + 0) = 2 * 0x + 1 = 1$

$T (1) = T (0x ^ 2 + 0x + 1) = 0$

solution $(2x, 1,0)$